# CSS Hover Jitter - Background Color

Tags: html, css

If you hover to the corner of the "x" you will get a jitter from the :hover effect of changing the background color.

I looked into `pseudo` solutions but I couldn't find anything for background transitions.

Can anyone provide a fix for the jitter without creating additional markup?

```css
.feed__btn {
    display: flex;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #6f6f90;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
.feed__btn:hover {
    color: white;
    font-size: 6px;
        background-color: #e05e7f;
}
```

```html
<span class="rmTag feed__btn feed__btn--unfollow">×</span>
```

Comment: Jittering might be the result of the `span` element changing size when hovered - possibly because the `font-size` changes from `12px` to `6px`. If you remove the font-size property in the hover state, does the jitter still occur?

Comment: You are right. So it's a font issue. What is the fix to accommodate the change in font size?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if your span size of 12px cannot (quite) fit a font size of 12px. I just ran a jsfiddle of your code making the width and height equal to 14px and cannot reproduce the jitter. Whereas I could reproduce it with the original size of 12px.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `background-color` from `transition`:

```css
.feed__btn {
    display: flex;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #6f6f90;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: /* background-color */ 0.25s;
}
.feed__btn:hover {
    color: white;
    font-size: 6px;
        background-color: #e05e7f;
}
```

```html
<span class="rmTag feed__btn feed__btn--unfollow">×</span>
```

Comment: I just tried this in the jsfiddle I'd created and it did not solve the problem. the hover still caused jitter.

Comment: @Neil, I run it here without any jitters. Why don't you add a link to your fiddle?

Comment: With different results, is it possible the issue is actually extending from font rendering implementations in different browsers? The original example seems to jitter in Chrome, but I'm not seeing the same issue in Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/zojn306u/

Comment: @user2921551, the original example jitters in Chrome, FF and Safari for me.

Comment: @KoshVery I just added `padding: 1px` to the span and it seemed to resolve the jitter on Chrome for me. I think @Neil is right in that the font-size is overflowing its container.

Comment: @KoshVery My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mntuzrov/ this is without the transition and without my fix, or the padding of 1px, which also seems to fix it.

Comment: @Neil, huge thanks, your fiddle contains code which differs from mine. So unfortunately your test is incorrect.

Comment: @KoshVery the only difference in the two codes is that yours has the line:     transition: /* background-color */ 0.25s; and when I insert that the jitter still occurs, certainly with the Chrome browser I'm using on my Windows system.

Comment: @Neil, that difference was a key point of my answer. And with that I do not see any jitters  in Chrome, FF and Safari on my mac.